# Why do my questions not get views/answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality, stats

Most of my questions get little to no views or answers. I have seen questions, where I believe are of 'lesser quality' than mine (i.e. Tagging, formatting or asking a relevant question) receive an absurd amount of attention.

Now I understand there is not an answer to *all* questions, but apart from setting a bounty for a question, there seems to be no method to grab attention to a question.

For users who have amounted tens of thousands of 'reputation points' this could be a good idea, using 50 points to draw in users, but for someone with only a few hundred points (and I know this sight isn't so much about points), it could be seen as silly to relinquish 50 points bounty to a question that may not attract a solid answer.

Here is a list of some of my questions:

- [Money Management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28543/money-management)
- [Office 365 Task integration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/office-365-task-integration)
- [PC Maintenence Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31886/pc-maintenence-recommendations)
- [To-do list integrating with Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31957/to-do-list-integrating-with-exchange)
- [On Premise Backup Solution using Cipher](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/on-premise-backup-solution-using-cipher)
- [iOS Compatible Encryption Software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35922/ios-compatible-encryption-software)
- [Local "Sandbox" Browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37064/local-sandbox-browser)
- [Local 'Instagram' for parenthood](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/local-instagram-for-parenthood)
- [SSH and Telnet Client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37514/ssh-and-telnet-client)
- [iOS Web Application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37599/ios-web-application)

I just want to know what sort of improvement(s) need to be made to help qualify these questions a little nicer, and how we can go about generating at least more reviews.

I know some of these may be seen as duplicates, but even then they should be marked as such.

Comment: Keeping in mind that questions without any answer, upvote, few comments and less than one visit per day are automatically deleted after a while without any warning, regardless of the quality of the question (I find these automatic deletions to be nonsense and a complete disregard to user content http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2459/903).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt (rhetorical point) When a question gets little-to-no response, people beg — *beg* — to let them ask it again. So **after a year** of apathy towards a question, isn't it better to clear that slate to let someone ask the question anew ... instead of just hoping a long-forgotten post will simply do better later and, potentially, black a better version from being asked?

Comment: @RobertCartaino From the standpoint of the OP who asked the long-forgotten post, the automatic deletion is a pain as 1) there is no warning that the question is deleted 2) if you're not a 10k+ user, it is quite difficult if not impossible to see which questions have been deleted. Asking a question sometimes take over one hour, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179 Aside from disrespecting the OP's time and effort, automatic deletion may encourage them not to spend too much time asking questions, since they may get deleted unnoticed and with no possibility to recover them.

Comment: @RobertCartaino It shouldn't be too difficult to design a system that allows other users to rewrite and repost a forgotten question, if that's what's the community wants, without having these two downsides (deletion the question with no notice + no possibility to recover the question). Simply adding a notice and extending the list of deleted questions to X years would already be a huge improvement.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've long thought (and argued) that hiding deleted content from an author's profile is a huge mistake and is *way* more of a deterrent (and hugely annoying) than helpful.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I guess we agree then. Who do we need to convince to make it happen? The community consensus also seems opposed to hiding deleted questions: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/178179)

Comment: Doesn't editing the question postpone automatic deletions? If a question is important I expect the OP to keep an eye on it. I could not find an answer to this. (I conclude from [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247970/prevent-questions-with-bounty-from-being-auto-deleted) that *starting a bounty* does not delay deletion).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*It's always helpful (and encouraged!) if folks can suggest ways to improve an author's posts; but that aside…*</sup>

Your questions are ***not*** receiving unusually low view counts relative to this site. This site often has low view counts on many posts, so low participation rates just seem endemic to this site. In reality, your posts seem to be about *on par* with the rest of the site.

Anecdotally, I sampled few of the questions you linked above and compared them to site average for questions asked in that same time frame. As you can see (below), you are receiving about the same number of views as other questions asked at that time on this site.

`Question   Total    System 
 Asked      Views   Average 
--------    -----   ------- 
 18 Nov        13        14 
 15 Nov        37        17 
 29 Oct        17        12 
 06 Aug         6        18 
 09 May        22        31 
 05 Feb        58        53`

Comment: Is the problem, then, that this site is not well-known? I only know of it because SO people will scoff and derisively mention this SE when complained that their "no recommendation" rules make no sense.

Comment: By the way, I do like that the Software Recs exists, and I just posted a question that absolutely cannot be rephrased to fit SO. I just feel that for such a universal problem, it doesn't feel to be thought to stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to make your question titles a bit more self-explaining.
Look at a few of your titles:

- Local “Sandbox” Browser
- Local 'Instagram' for parenthood
- iOS Web Application

While these titles might sound clear to you, I did not have any idea what they meant before reading the full question. That's true for most of the questions you listed above, actually.

Solution: Make your titles more explicit, even if that means they get five times longer.

Another general trick: Make your posts more discoverable by search engines, by including relevant keywords. For short questions, you can even paraphrase a bit, that helps make the question extra clear and makes it more findable.